# Find the Maclaurin Series for this particular function

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, euler-maclaurin

Let a value $x_1 \in \mathbb{R}$, $x_1 > 0$ such that $\sin(x_1)=\sin(x_1^2)$. Next, \begin{equation*}
f(x) = \left\{
        \begin{array}{ll}
            -\sin(x) & x \leq -x_1 \\
            \sin(x^2) & -x_1 < x < x_1 \\
            \sin(x) & x \geq x_1
        \end{array}
    \right.
\end{equation*}

Where is the function f(x) equal to its Maclaurin series?

So we know that for the Macluarin series, $f^{(n)}(0)=0$, since we are working with a sine function here. We can use the taylor series for $\sin(x)$ as the Maclaurin series. However, we see that the Macluarin series does not represent the function eveywhere. I conclude that the Macluarin series only works for values $[-x_1, x_1]$ (recall that $x_1$ is the value we defined in the beginning).

Comment: MacLaurin means around the origin, so the series is that of $\sin {x^2}$ so it agrees when the piecewise function is $\sin {x^2}$

Comment: Ok, thanks for solving this (:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get it, since $\sin {x^2}$ is even and $\sin x$ is negative on $-x_1 < x < 0$  they need the extra minus sign on the left for continuity

$$  x_1 + x_1^2 = \pi $$
$$  x_1^2 + x_1 - \pi = 0 $$
$$  x_1 = \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1+4\pi}}{2},  $$
positive  means  $  x_1 = \frac{-1 + \sqrt{1+4\pi}}{2} \approx 1.3416277 < \frac{\pi}{2},  $

Comment: great answer! so is my solution right?